# How to create Object with dynamic keys with value from string in pure js?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an object with dynamic keys with key ID and value as a name from a string that I'm getting through API.
Below is my API

```
["PHP", "Project Management", "PHP dynamic website", "Ecommerce", "Magento", "Magento Websites"]
```

I want to convert it to following response

```
         [
            { id: 0, name: "PHP" },
            { id: 1, name: "Project Management" },
            { id: 2, name: "PHP dynamic website" },
            { id: 3, name: "Ecommerce" }
         ]
```

Comment: Why is `"Magento", "Magento Websites"` not in your result?

Comment: @NickParsons I believe out of pure lazyness lol

Comment: Did you try using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with an index? What part are you having trouble with?  Or do you just want to be shown a complete solution?

Comment: @Gibor.. yea right.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map each name to an object which uses the index as the `id` and the value as the `name` property:

```js
const arr = ["PHP", "Project Management", "PHP dynamic website", "Ecommerce", "Magento", "Magento Websites"];

const res = arr.map((name, id) => ({id, name}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `forEach` loop, and use the iterator as the key:

```js
var apiResponse = ["PHP", "Project Management", "PHP dynamic website", "Ecommerce", "Magento", "Magento Websites"],
    newResponse = [ ];

apiResponse.forEach(function(name, index) {
   newResponse.push({ id: index, name: name });
});
 
 console.log(newResponse);
```

Comment: I think using a functional `map` is more concise than an imperative `forEach`.  But both are good to know how to use.  Both are provided the index of the array element as an optional argument to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your usecase: Assuming newArr is the type of array you want
// ar is the initial array

```js
ar=["PHP", "Project Management", "PHP dynamic website", "Ecommerce", "Magento", "Magento Websites"];
newArr=[];
for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
  let obj={id:i,name:ar[i]};
  newArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: welcome to SO, you can create a [`running snippet`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

There no dynamic keys in here tho, all your objects and their keys look the same... Simply use the array.forEach() method to loop on all array values and push them into object into a new array:

```
let res = [];
sourceArr.forEach( (name, index) => {
   res.push( {id: index, name: name} );
}
```

Easy as that.

Comment: This is may look compact, but it's actually wordier than necessary.  Consider that `{name}` can be used instead of `{name: name}`, and therefore it's more fluid to name the `index` as `id` to take advantage of the same.  Also using `map` will allow you to forgo the `push`, which is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I used traditional way. hope you are looking for this one.

```
B = ["PHP", "Project Management", "PHP dynamic website", "Ecommerce", "Magento", "Magento Websites"]
result = [];

for (i=0;i<B.length;i++)
{
    result[i] = "{id:"+[i]+ "name:"+B[i]+"}";
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is wrong in many ways.  Most importantly, you're outputting an array of strings, but they've asked for an array of objects.